# Delete Rows based on Values in Two Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that I need to delete rows based on the values from two different cells.

The initial excel sheet is created from a report that will populate the data from the previous month up until the current day. Depending on the day the report is ran I could have an extra three days or four days worth of data that I do not need.  I would like to delete the rows that I do not need based on the month and time columns.

Simplified Excel Sheet
[image]

I would like to delete everything past the last day of the month except for the initial data on the 1st at 0:00. In this example I would like to delete everything below row #4.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

So far I have tried the following and I can filter the data on the date column, but I have not been successful at combining the filter for the second column.

```
Sub Delete_Row_Cell_Contains_Text()
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Row = 15
    For i = Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = "12" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Cells(i, 1) = "12" And Cells(i, 2) > 0 Then` should do it. But I actually don't how `Cells(i, 1) = "12"` worked for you because none of the cells has the value `12` actually. So maybe you should use `If Month(Cells(i, 1)) = 12 And Cells(i, 2) > 0 Then`

Comment: If your data already in two level sorted (column A and B, ascending), maybe you can try to find the first occurence of current month and year. Something like this `dt = "01 " & Format(Date, "mmm yyyy")` ... `r1 = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(dt)), Range("A:A"), 0) + 1` ... `r2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` ... `Rows(r1 & ":" & r2).Select`. r1 will be the row number of the first occurence of 1 dec 2022 + 1. r2 will be the last row number with data. Test, if the `.select` always give you the expected result with various of data, then change `.select` into `.entirerow.delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub Delete_Row_Cell_Contains_Text()
    
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, currMonth As Long, dt As Date
    Dim keepDateTime
    
    currMonth = Month(Date)
    keepDateTime = DateSerial(Year(Date), currMonth, 1) 'date/time row to keep
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1 'from last date up...
        dt = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Month(dt) <> currMonth - 1 Then 'if not this month-1
            'if not the first of this month at midnight
            If dt + ws.Cells(i, 2).Value <> keepDateTime Then
                ws.Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```